# Value assigned never used. Delphi bug or code bug?

Tags: delphi

This code is part of a third party component I am using in my application.
I am trying to solve all possible problems related to hint in my application.
But I can not understand this.
Delphi Compiler marks first line of this code for a hint "Value assigned to NewState never used!.
I just want to understand situation

```
  NewState := STATE_UNCHECKED;   //Value assigned never used?Really?
  while ( Node <> nil ) and ( Node.Parent <> nil ) do
  begin
    Node := Node.Parent.GetFirstChild;
    CheckedCount := 0;
    UnCheckedCount := 0;
    while True do
    begin
     ....
      if ( Node.StateIndex = STATE_PARTCHECKED ) or
         ( ( CheckedCount > 0 ) and ( UnCheckedCount > 0 ) ) then
      begin
        NewState := STATE_PARTCHECKED; ///assign value on condition
        Break;
      end;

      if Node.GetNextSibling = nil then
      begin
        if CheckedCount > 0 then
          NewState := STATE_CHECKED //assign value on condition
        else
          NewState := STATE_UNCHECKED;
        Break;
      end
      else
        Node := Node.GetNextSibling;
    end;
    Node := Node.Parent;
    if Node <> nil then
      SetState( Node,  NewState );
  end;
```

But when both of this statments are false this value must be used.Am i wrong?

```
 if ( Node.StateIndex = STATE_PARTCHECKED ) or
             ( ( CheckedCount > 0 ) and ( UnCheckedCount > 0 ) ) then
```

and

```
if Node.GetNextSibling = nil then
```

**UPDATE**

answers are correct .The Break Statment runs only after a new value assigned to variable and overwriting first value. then assigned value is never used.

a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var x,y,z,k:integer;
begin
   X:=1;
   Y:=strtoint(edit1.text);
   Z:=Strtoint(edit2.text);
   K:=Strtoint(edit3.text);
     while true do
     begin
      If Z=y*2 then
      begin
        X:=2;
        Break;
      end;

      If Y=3 then
      begin
        If K=7 then
        begin
        X:=3;
        Break;
        end
        else
        begin
        x:=6;
        Break;
        end;
      end
     end;

    showmessage(inttostr(x));

end;
```

Comment: If I were a _human compiler_, I would say the same. The assigned value `STATE_UNCHECKED` is not compared in that `if` statement.

Comment: Ah, I think that I see it. The inner loop is a 'While TRUE'. The only ways out of that loop require that NewState be assigned. So the compiler is correct.

Comment: Sadly, you didn't show the entire function, and you showed loads of code that was not necessary. This could have been a good question if only you'd provided a [mcve].

Comment: dear @DavidHeffernan , As I said , This is not my code. I was Trying to solve all hints ( you know an assigned but not used value or declared but not used variable in many cases represenst a possible bug in code ).
I noticied this one in a component's source.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
Also I was not sure including lines that 3rd party component name is clearly there . i did not know this is allowed or not when it is not free component set .(like a kind of advertisement).
Thank you for your reply

Comment: Don't post the entire code. Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If both the statement you highlight are FALSE then the **while True** loop continues. The only ways out of this loop require the NewState value to be assigned. So The compiler is correct.

Answer (score 2):

First, you misunderstand the concept "is used". In this context it means "is the variable ***read*** for any purpose *before* its value is changed again or the variable goes out of scope". You seem to think it means "is the variable name referred to again"; so you're incorrectly thinking when the existing value is being *overwritten* it "is being used".

---

You clearly haven't shown all the code. Whether the missing code is relevant? Without seeing it, I can't be sure.

But from the code you *do show*: the value in assigned in the first line is overwritten without being read in the `while True` loop. i.e. initial assignment ***is** never used* up to that point. However, whether those lines are reached is not clear because of the conditional code leading there.

The only place where `NewState` *is* read is in the line `SetState(Node, NewState);`. As Dsm points out, in the code you ***do*** show, the only way to get there is by breaking out of the `while True` loop immediately *after* **overwriting** the initial value.

---

You don't say which version of Delphi you're using, but I don't think old versions were capable of picking up this slightly complex case. It should be noted that there are certainly complex cases where compilers are incapable of making an accurate determination. But since this warning involves the compiler removing the line from compiled output, these cases are typically only reported when the logic clearly indicates it's *not used*.

Comment: I removed a part of code that make no sesce with this issue.
And you are right. That is Because only way out of while loop is after changing this variable

Comment: @Shahram My point is that your question implied a misunderstanding of the "Value assigned ... never used" hint. This made you ill-equipped to reliably determine if the part of code you removed _really was_ relevant. This particular hint (and the closely related 'variable not initialised' warning) are both subtly affected by: `Exit`, `Break`, loops, `try..finally`, `try..except`, `with`, branching, `raise`, and reference parameters. I believe you're now in a better position to this decision. But for future reference, you're better off testing and then asking about a **complete** [mcve].